# Wunderground API

Tags: jquery, json, api

I'm attempting to:

1. Display the Hourly 1-day forecast
2. Display the condition for each hour
3. Display the temperature for each hour

The code that I have right now is:

```
 <script>
    $.ajax({                             
        url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/c56b47e853a45b50/hourly/q/OH/Huber_Heights.json",
        dataType : "json", 
        success : function(parsed_json) { 
            var hour1 = parsed_json["hourly_forecast"]['hour']; 

                $(".box2").html( 
                'the answer is ' + hour1

                );

       } 
});
```

And I keep receiving an undefined answer.

To see my API sheet, copy the url into your browser.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: can you share which server side language you're using?

Comment: I'm not using any specific language. This is all jquery and html.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `parsed_json['hourly_forecast']` is an array, but you're referencing it as if it were an object. There are a bunch of objects inside `parsed_json['hourly_forecast']`. It's your job to loop through these and display them all, or decide which one you want to work with. E.g.

```
var hourlyForecast = parsed_json['hourly_forecast'];
for (var hour in hourlyForecast) {
  // do stuff with hour object here
}
```

Comment: I still don't get how to do this. (I'm a student and my teacher isn't doing very well) (plus I'm dyslexic which adds to the fun)